# Why might chkdsk not be able to repair a disk?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, chkdsk

I'm using Windows 10 Pro and I am trying to understand why windows disk repair might not work.

If I right-click on my `C:` drive and select `properties/tools/check` it tells me the disk has errors.

For a bit more detail I can open a cmd prompt window (as administrator) and type `chkdsk C:` it lists a couple of

> Attribute record.... from file record segment.... is corrupt

And a

> The total allocated size in attribute record... of file.... is incorrect

But no more than half a dozen errors in total

I can't repair this with `chkdsk c: /f /r /x` from the command prompt because it won't work if the disk is online. So I select the `repair drive` option from windows explorer. It reboots and displays the message

> scanning and repairing drive c: 100% complete

But if I go back to file explorer it still warns of errors, and if I run `chkdsk` again I get the same errors listed.

So, why can't windows repair these errors (and what can be done to fix it)

Other information:

- Windows is up-to-date except for the most recent 1/2 dozen updates.
- The disk errors are on drive `C:` and so is the operating system.
- Anti-virus is installed and up-to-date. (although has been disabled
  while working on this).
- The operating system is currently (mostly)
  behaving itself but has just started throwing the occasional tantrum.
- The drive is solid-state drive, don't know if it makes any
  difference. I'm assuming (correct me if I'm wrong) that the file
  explorer is just using `chkdsk` under the hood?

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: "So, why can't windows repair these errors " because they are not repairable, the drive may be failing.

Comment: @Moab - I know the operating system can't 'repair' a hard disk, but what it should do is mark the area's as 'bad' and make sure nothing gets written to them.

Comment: In my experience, if you can mark bad areas, the situation tends to get worse, so I would replace  the drive to save time and problems.

Comment: chkdsk c: /f /r   Should prompt you to run chkdsk on the next reboot.  Say Yes reboot and it should run.  If does not work try it second time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should get the manufacturer's disk app and check the disk with that.

CHKDSK  with /F will check the disk on the next reboot if it cannot do online repairs.

Be careful as CHKDSK repairs can alter damaged files so that you might not be able to restart. That has happened before. CHKDSK cannot repaired damaged areas of the disk.

Back up important data immediately in case you need to replace or rebuild your disk. It is probably time for a new disk.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is to check if the drivers of the SSD are updated (go to the manufacturer's website and check this).

In case you are facing with an error when running chkdsk, then try to run it from Windows Recovery Environment.

If the disk is old, then you should think of purchasing a new one.